# No git color schemes under rxvt/cygwin

Tags: git, colors, cygwin, terminal, rxvt

After getting tired of the default cygwin terminal, I decide to try `rxvt`. Everything seems fine except one thing: the color schemes for my git repositories stop working.

BTW other color schemes like the `vim` editor works fine under `rxvt`. I also ran this [script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349) to ensure that 256 colors are enabled.

My `~/.gitconfig` looks something like this:

```
[user]
  name = xyz
  email = xyz@abc.com    
[color]
  diff = auto
  status = auto
  branch = auto
[core]
  autocrlf = false
```

Comment: From the script you linked to: "doesn't work with rxvt and I don't know about other terms because it uses xterm color escapes..." and yet it worked?

Comment: Interesting, didn't notice that before. But that script did print out colors on my screen :)

Comment: Looking at the git source, I see explicit xterm character sequences for the colors, like `\033[31m` - my guess would be that those don't work in rxvt. The weird thing is that the script works. It looks like it's printing out essentially the same kinds of things, though they're 256 colors, not 16. Does rxvt somehow support 256 color xterm escape sequences, but not 16?

Comment: That could well be the case I guess.

Comment: Are you using Cygwin's git or a Windows git? Colours wouldn't work with the latter, as it would try to use Windows console APIs rather than escape sequences. Rxvt supports colour sequences just fine.

Comment: Good point. I was using msysgit. I just tried cygwin git and it worked fine.

Comment: @gnfalex found a way to use `msysgit` and the colored output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If change all settings in ~/.gitconfig color section from "auto" to "always", then MSYSGit coloring work even in rxvt/mintty

```
[color]
    ui = always
    status = always
    branch = always
    diff = always
    interactive = always
```

Comment: Impressive! Works flawlessly for me!

Comment: Also helped me in cygwin's git when I mysteriously lost colors everywhere after using GNU screen once.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was looking for this solution and now my Cygwin work perfectly

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to suggestion by [ak2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237062/ak2), I solved this problem by switching from msysgit to cygwin's git.